# need help in macros and access DB with external oracle DB connectivity?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, macros

In existing Microsoft Access DataBase we have table that inputvalue mapped from oracle DB,I hope with help of macros its getting purged into the access DB from Oracle DB. here my question is there is anyway to identify the existing mapping between oracle DB Field to Access DB Field? Please help on this.

Comment: are these linked tables from Oracle to access, or Pass through queries?

Comment: Harrison is there is any way to identify the link?

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA:

```
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        ''Linked table
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            Debug.Print tdf.Connect
            ''Local name
            Debug.Print tdf.Name
            ''Source name
            Debug.Print tdf.SourceTableName

            For Each fld In tdf.Fields
               ''Local name
                Debug.Print fld.Name
               ''Source name
                Debug.Print fld.SourceField
            Next
        End If
    Next
```